# Solving an ODE by adding a constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the ODE

$$y'(t)+2y(t)=3$$

by shifting the function, that is, replacing $y(t) \longrightarrow y(t) + const$ with an appropriate constant.

I thought about replacing $y(t)$ by $y(t)+\frac{3}{2}$

$$\implies y'+2(y+\frac{3}{2})=3 \iff y'+2y=0$$

$$\implies y=Ce^{-2t}$$

1. Why am I allowed to just shift the function? How can I be sure that it doesn't change my solution
2. After shifting the function by $\frac{3}{2}$ and solving the resulting ODE, how do I get the solution to my original ODE?

Comment: You are doing a substitution. What's confusing is that you use $y(t)$ on both sides of the substitution. Use unique names and the problem will disappear: $y(t) = z(t) + \frac32$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notation is confusing. Writing instead $y = y_1 + 3/2$ we have

$$y' + 2y = 3 \quad\Longleftrightarrow \quad y_1' + 2y_1 = 0$$

Thus $y_1 = Ce^{-2t}$ and $y = Ce^{-2t} + 3/2$.

I hope the change helps clarify what is going on.

Comment: Nice! Makes much more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @bluemoon what makes the "appropriate constant" appropriate is that it is a particular solution to the ODE (try $y=\frac32$, in your ODE). The solution to an inhomogeneous ODE can be found by adding the general solution to a particular one, which is exactly what the substitution does: notice that the ODE with $y_1$ is homogeneous. "Shifting the function" another (and obscure) way to say that you have to find the general and a particular solution to solve this inhomogeneous ODE.

Comment: @null Awesome! That actually closed some knowledge gaps for me. Thank you very very much!